Bound on cardinality of set such that any selected subsets will have non-empty intersection
There is a set of cardinality $S$. From this set, we select $X$ subsets, each of cardinality $R$. What is the upper bound on $S$, in terms of $X$ and $R$, such that ANY selected $X$ sets will have a non-empty intersection?

What have you tried? Please add your progress to the body of the question. Otherwise it will be likely closed. For example, do you know the answer for R=1? For R=2? Generalize.

@MartinBrandenburg For the X=2 case, it was easy as |S|<2R guarantees overlap. But for X>=3, it can getting difficult. Hence I asked here. I hope this helps.

@WorkingFisherman can you try using the hole principle and form upper bound formula
.itz doable only.....try one time
u will be getting $S \ge R*(X-1)+1$

To ensure that every set of $X$ subsets has a non-empty intersection, at least one element must be common to all $X$ subsets.

@riteshwar That is exactly how I tried to do it. My reasoning is: There are $X$ sets, from which 1 element is common in all these sets. So, $R-1$ elements need to be picked for each set. In other words, $(R-1)\times X$ elements need to be picked. So, if $S-1<(R-1)\times X\implies S<1+X\times(R-1)$, we have our condition. But for $X=3, R=2$, this bound yields $S<1+3=4$. But choosing 3 sets from ${1,2,3}$ of cardinality 2 is ${1,2},{1,3},{2,3}$ which have empty intersection. Hence, my confusion.

Please allow me to use different variables since using upper case letters to denote numbers, especially when dealing with sets is off-putting to me. I have rephrased the question below.
We are to select $k$ subsets each of size $r$ from the set $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We are guaranteed that the intersection of these $k$ subsets is always non-empty. What can we say about $n$?
I claim that $\displaystyle n < \frac{k \cdot r}{k-1}$.
Suppose the condition is not sufficient. Then, there is a collection of $k$ subsets of $[n]$ of size $r$ each, whose intersection is empty. For $i \in [n]$, let $c_i$ denote the number of subsets in which $i$ appears in. So, we have $c_i \leqslant (k-1)$ for each $i \in [n]$ since otherwise $i$ is in the intersection of the $k$ subsets. So, $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \leqslant (k-1)n < k \cdot r$. But the quantity $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i$ must be exactly $k \cdot r$ since we have $k$ subset of size $r$ each. We got a contradiction.
To prove the condition is necessary, it suffices to show an example where it fails for $\displaystyle n = \frac{k \cdot r}{k-1}$. Partition $[n]$ into $k$ parts $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{k}$, each of size $\displaystyle \frac{n}{k}$. Define $Y_i := [n] - X_i$ for each $i \in [k]$. Note that the size of $Y_i$ is $\displaystyle \frac{n}{k}\cdot(k-1)=r$. Also note that for each element $j \in [n]$, there exists an $i \in [k]$ such that $j \notin Y_i$ by definition. Hence, $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^k Y_i = \emptyset$.

I have one question. In the necessity part, what if $\frac{n}{k}$ is not an integer?

@user14111 but the necessity part has the condition that $n=\frac{kr}{k-1}$

@user14111 ah okay. My bad. I got confused with the proof of necessity part, where the author gave a counter-example with $n=\frac{kr}{k-1}$. Thanks. I understood it.

@WorkingFisherman I had been wondering what happens when $\displaystyle \frac{n}{k}$ is NOT an integer too but unfortunately I could not spend much time to think about it. If you have understood, can you please explain to me too? Thanks!
